# Python pandas Merging 2 dataframe of the same size

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframe that are the same size.

I am not sure if "merge" is the right word here, but I would like to create a new dataframe with values that is minimum between the two.

```
df_1 
             ask           bid 
A       0                    2   
B       0.643319      1.000000    
C       0.722802      0.920498

df_2
             ask           bid 
A       1             0.643319   
B       0.643319      0    
C       0.722802      0.920498         

df_3
             ask           bid 
A       0             0.643319  
B       0.643319      0    
C       0.722802      0.920498
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add an expected result. Requirement is not clear from the question

Comment: I added the expect result. Df3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df_3 = df_1.where(df_1 < df_2, df_2)
```

`df_1.where` returns the value from `df_1` when the condition, `df_1 < df_2` is True, and the corresponding value from `df_2` when the condition is False.

Comment: worked perfectly... Why are you guys so good at this? Thanks man.

Comment: 90% of the problems are solved with 10% of the tools. So be happy every time you encounter something new -- there is a great chance you'll have an opportunity to use it again :)

Comment: @WeiZeng I noticed you've never accepted an answer before... you have the ability to accept whatever answer you find the most useful to your questions with the green check-mark to the left.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be [`numpy.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html).

```
>>> df1
   bid  ask
0    4    3
1    4    4

>>> df2 
   bid  ask
0    9    2
1    5    1

>>> pd.DataFrame(np.minimum(df1, df2))
   bid  ask
0    4    2
1    4    1
```