# Comparison over > and < between values of 2 data frames in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Am having two dataframes,as df1 & df2

```
 df1                  df2
 A  10                A 7
 B  1500              B 1100
 C  5                 C 10
 D  100               D 60
```

Now i need to write code for comparing each df1['A'] over ">" or "<" with df2['A']
and so on..can someone suggest the function to write the comparison and return greater value not any boolean result.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42233908/190597

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: you want a function that returns a dataframe (df3) where `df3.iloc[i] == max(df1.iloc[i], df2.iloc[i])`?

There might be a simpler way, but here's something that works:

```
s1 = pd.Series((10, 1500, 5, 100), index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
s2 = pd.Series((7, 1100, 10, 60), index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
s3 = pd.concat((s1[s1 > s2], s2[s2 > s1]), axis=0)
s3
A      10
B    1500
D     100
C      10
```

When you call `s1[s1 > s2]`, it returns all elements of s1 that are greater than the corresponding element of s2 (likewise for `s2[s2 > s1]`). Then you just have to concatenate these two together; axis=0 means to do it row-wise.

This *does* get your index out of order. You can fix that, if you want, by just sorting it after:

```
s3.sort_index()
A      10
B    1500
C      10
D     100
```

@unutbu's answer (linked in his comment to the OP's question) is probably more straightforward:

```
df_3 = df_1.where(df_1 > df_2, df_2)
```

This returns the value from df_1 when the condition holds (the value is larger), otherwise it returns the value from df_2.

(This does seem a duplicate of the question he links, but the title here is perhaps easier to find in a Google search for this task? Something like "Elementwise < (Greater Than) Between Pandas DataFrames" might also go well)

Comment: Can we use & condition to filter out data in series s1 & s2 for eg  `s1[s1< maxima & s1>mean]`

Comment: TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "Series"

Comment: What exactly are you running when you get the TypeError?When you want to apply boolean operations to Series, you have to enclose them in parenthesis (I think you also want to select along the index?): `s1.loc[(s1< maxima) & (s1>mean)]`